# latexmk not returning cursor back in vim

Tags: latexmk, vim, vim-latex

First, one disclaimer: I don't know if I should put it here or in `vim`. But I hope there are many people common here.

I am using [AsyncRun](https://github.com/skywind3000/asyncrun.vim) to compile all my projects and files, and for this question, I am having problem with LaTex. My AsyncRun is:

```
" AsyncRun {{{
" Quick run via <F10>
nnoremap <F10> :call <SID>compile_and_run()<CR>
inoremap <buffer> <F10> <Esc> :call <SID>compile_and_run()<CR>
function! s:compile_and_run()
  exec 'w'
  if &filetype == 'c'
    exec "AsyncRun! gcc % -o %<; time ./%<"
  elseif &filetype == 'fortran'
    exec "AsyncRun! gfortran -Wall % -o %<; time ./%<"
  elseif &filetype == 'tex'
    exec "AsyncRun! latexmk -pdflatex=lualatex -quiet -pdf -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape -synctex=1 -pvc %"
  elseif &filetype == 'sh'
    exec "AsyncRun! time bash %"
  elseif &filetype == 'python'
    exec "AsyncRun! time python3 %"
  endif
  exec '<CR>'
endfunction
let g:asyncrun_open = 15
"}}}
```

With that I also have, in my .vimrc:

```
"LaTeX: {{{
augroup FT_LaTex
  autocmd BufReadPost *.tex setlocal filetype=tex
  au FileType tex let b:ale_linters =  ['texlab']
  au filetype tex let b:ale_fixers = ['latexindent', 'remove_trailing_lines', 'trim_whitespace']  
  let g:tex_flavor = 'latex'
  " let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat = 'pdf'
  " let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf = 'evince_dbus.py'
  " let g:Tex_Debug = 1
  " let g:Tex_DebugLog = '/tmp/vim-latex-suite.log'
  au FileType tex inoremap "" ``"<++><esc>4hi
  " au FileType tex  nnoremap <buffer> <Leader>lm :up!<cr>:! latexmk -pdf -quiet --shell-escape %<cr>
  au FileType *.tex set vim=~/bin/vims.py
  au filetype tex syntax region texZone start='\\begin{minted}' end='\\end{minted}'
  au filetype tex imap `/ frac<c-r>=UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()<cr>
  au filetype tex imap FBF FBF<c-r>=UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()<cr>
  au filetype tex imap FIT FIT<c-r>=UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()<cr>
  au filetype tex imap FTT FTT<c-r>=UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()<cr>
augroup END
"}}}
```

Now, the problem is, I am expecting, after compiling, the cursor should come back to my tex buffer, but that is not the case. It is actually sticking to the quickfix window, and I need to press Esc to get the cursor back.

If I dont use `-pvc` option, then it is working fine.

Comment: do you know what `-pvc` does? Continous preview mode it never stops! so of course it never returns to vim. DId you mean `-pv` instead? I use `-pvc` all the time, but I never start latex from an editor anymore. I start my editor, and start `latexmk -pvc -pdf` in a separate terminal

Comment: I recommend to use [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) plugin for vim.

Comment: @daleif: Is it normal that with `-pv`, the previewer wont update itself after reprocess? So, with `-pv`, after preview, I have to close evince?

Comment: No evince normally updates it self automatically